# Array Size in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I wonder when should we include the size of an array in [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) and when we don't need to include the size of an array. Because in some cases, when I don't include the size of the array, there are error messages that tell "**object reference not set to an instance of an object**".

```
Dim ClusterMember(,) As Decimal or 

Dim ClusterMember(500,100) As Decimal
```

Thank you for your response. But I found in the case below, the array SplitTemp() work well without declaring it size size when it is declares.

```
Dim ClusterMember(200, 20) As String
Dim SplitTemp() As String

Streamer = IO.File.OpenText(txtOpenFile.Text)
MyString = Streamer.ReadToEnd.Split(vbNewLine)

SplitResult = MyString(0).Split(",")
DataDimention = SplitResult.Length - 1
DataNumber = MyString.Length

For i = 0 To DataNumber - 1
   SplitTemp = MyString(i).Split(",")
      For j = 0 To DataDimention
         ClusterMember(i, j) = SplitTemp(j)
      Next
Next
```

Comment: Avoid the problem all together and use collections where possible. `Dim clusterMember as New Collection(Of Decimal)` and don't worry about the length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st array declaration declares an array but it doesn't yet have a size.  Using it will produce a NullReferenceException when you try to access an element.  An array *must* have a size before it usable, you do so either when you declare it, like your 2nd example, or do it later with the Redim statement:

```
Dim ClusterMember(,) As Decimal
''...
Redim ClusterMember(500, 100)
```

Which creates an array that can store 501 x 101 elements.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I found in the case that I add above, the array SplitTemp() work well without declaring size when it is declares.

Comment: Because it is assigned from the String.Split() method.  Which created the array and returned it.  There are excellent introductory books about vb.net available, you'd be well ahead by reading one.